# Does helmfile sync will redeploy all existing helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have a few services running on a kubernetes cluster, and I use Helm Chart where I placed all my services. However, I was asked to transfer Helm Charts into Helmfile.
If I use

```
helmfile import myrepo/mychart
helmfile sync
```

Will it redeploy and substitute existing running pods  or It will deploy just deploy  additional services mentioned

Comment: `helmfile diff` will show you what `helmfile apply` will do.  I believe Helmfile mostly wraps `helm` commands, so if you already have the same charts installed in the same namespaces with the same names, I'd expect it to not want to do anything.

Comment: @DavidMaze Could you please explain why it would not do anything?

Comment: If your `helmfile.yaml` lists all of the same releases you've separately `helm install`ed, it won't see any change.  (But if you've added additional releases those should get installed.)  At any rate, the `helmfile diff` will show you what will actually change and that might be the clearest answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helm uses a packaging format called charts. A chart is a collection of files that describe a related set of Kubernetes resources. A single chart might be used to deploy something simple, like a memcached pod, or something complex, like a full web app stack with HTTP servers, databases, caches, and so on.

Helmfile is a declarative spec for deploying helm charts. It lets you...
Keep a directory of chart value files and maintain changes in version control.
Apply CI/CD to configuration changes.
Periodically sync to avoid skew in environments.

To avoid upgrades for each iteration of helm, the helmfile executable delegates to helm - as a result, helm must be installed.

Like @DavidMaze suggested, use helm diff command first to determine the changes and then use helm sync command for applying them.